# Why is my DHCP server assigning an address outside of the DHCP scope?

Tags: ip, dhcp-server

In my home network, I have wireless router and DHCP server running on it. When I try to connect with my laptop to my home network, I get following IP address:

```
169.254.76.100
255.255.0.0
```

That is odd, because my DHCP address scope is starting from 192.168.1.100 to 192.168.1.199. When I restart my wireless network card, same problem.

When I run `ipconfig` in Command Prompt,I get following results.

**NOTE: Without any problem I can connect to network in friends house!**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

That is a self-assigned/APIPA address.  Your machine is unable to get an address likely either through a cabling/switch issue or your DHCP server really isn't answering requests.

Comment: With another laptop I connect to my home network without any problem !

Comment: Is the only thing you are changing the laptops themselves?  Are you using the same cable, the same switch port, etc?  Do you have any MAC filters/locks anywhere?

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed you are using a wireless connection.  Are you you sure you are really connected and do you have any MAC filters set up on your AP?

Comment: I don't have any mac filters? I tried with my mobile phone, and third computer, and no problem at all, but when I try with my laptop, I can't connect !

Comment: Anyone, this thing is driving me crazy!

Comment: @Mr.M Have you tried assigning it a static IP address?

Answer (score 0):

1. Reboot the router and PC, no connection, proceed to 2
2. Assign your adapter a static IP address in the same range, so something like this:

   ```
   192.168.1.50
   255.255.255.0
   192.168.1.1
   ```

   No connection, reset to dhcp and proceed to 3
3. Update the router firmware using a network cable from router to PC. No connection, proceed to 4
4. Disable firewalls on PC. No connection, proceed to 5
5. Update wireless card driver.

What is the security for the wireless? I have seen issues with WPA2 and XP PCs, just a thought.